# How do I apply SQLCipher to my Login database?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-keystore, sqlcipher

I am creating a Login application that can be reused for any other application with a little tweaking to the UI and features. The user inputs their username and password into the text boxes, and either stores it with the Create Account button, or it verifies it against the Login database to check if the input username/password combination are correct.

I'm just not quite certain how to use the guide found here on the Android Developers website:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/cryptography

This refers to KeyStore for more secure encryption, which I would like to use if I can figure out how to implement it. However, it really probably doesn't have to be super complex either, and I might want to utilize an easier solution if I have to.

Are there any good guides that I could use to figure out what I'm supposed to do? I haven't seen anything particularly useful from doing some Google searching. I believe I have created/used the code to generate a key, but I don't know what to do from here. Any guidance in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

So far, I have reused the code from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaSck7jBDbw) to get code for generating a key, but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: See SQLCipher's Github readme for more info: https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher

Comment: Darshan, I read over what I needed to from that readme many times. I should have included that in my post. As I said, Google searching isn't providing much detail. I've already refactored the passphrase/factory/room code from the readme for my own project, but now the application isn't running correctly, so I'll have to do more debugging now.